# Android - Pass Title to ExoPlayer's Custom Layout

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

in my Android App I have a custom layout for my `PlayerView`:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:use_controller="true"
            app:resize_mode="fill"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_player_control_view"/>
```

As you can see the custom layout is called `exo_player_control_view.xml` which contains play&stop icon + a TextView for the title of the video:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="test"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/play"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pause"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It works fine but my question is this: How can I pass the title of the video to the TextView at runtime. In my app the user selects a video item from a list and I let it play in a new Fragment which contains the `PlayerView` in its layout. But I don't know how to pass the title of the video item to the custom layout `exo_player_control_view.xml`. Normally, I would do it with data binding but I don't know how to do it in this case.

There are some SO threads out there in the wild but none of them was helpful.

Comment: This should work:

TextView videoTitle = findViewById(R.id.title); 
runOnUiThread(() -> {
  videoTitle.setText(“VIDEO TITLE”);
});

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the view using `findViewById` like this: `mySimpleExoPlayerView.findViewById(R.id.title)`